# Getting "Debug Assertion" in creating S3 Client using AWS SDK for C++

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

I am a beginner in AWS and I have got a requirement to write/upload a file to S3 bucket.

Below is the code snippet which I wrote, but I am getting Debug Error! `abort() has been called` in 4th line  `Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(config);`

(This is just a code snippet, not complete code):-

```
    Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
    const Aws::String region = "us-east-1";
    config.region = region;
    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(config);

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest request;
    request.SetBucket("parquetbucketforlossengine");
    request.SetKey(filename);

    const std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream> input_data =
        Aws::MakeShared<Aws::StringStream>("");
    *input_data << file_output_stream;

    request.SetBody(input_data);

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectOutcome outcome = s3_client.PutObject(request);

    if (!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cout << "Error: PutObjectBuffer: " <<
            outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Success: Object '" << filename << "'.";
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me on the above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An `assert()` is usually inserted for a situation which may exclusively result from programming errors (but not from e.g. wrong user input). If this happens in `Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(config);` then either the Amazon guys did something wrong or you passed values in `config` which are unexpected and unacceptable by the  `Aws::S3::S3Client` code. Before you send a bug report to Amazon you should carefully exclude that you did something wrong. Read the doc., have a look at the tutorials, and check whether `Aws::S3::S3Client` expects a pre-condition you haven't met.

Comment: Does it print anything else?

Comment: Btw. `abort()` is called for a reason when an `assert()` didn't hold. It stops the application immediately with a core dump (or something comparable) and gives you a chance to look at the "frozen" call stack. So, you can check what called what and maybe see what went wrong where and why.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a very basic mistake, I was not calling InitAPI and ShutDownAPI which is a pre condition for S3 Client configuration. It is working fine after adding them.